# Как написать скрипт в bat

Tags: bat

Как написать скрипт в bat файле чтобы за определенное время ты смог выполнить действие.
Есть пример таймера и по задумке оно должно было работать так, человеку дается 5 секунд на то чтобы вписать значение в переменную answer, но работает оно не так как надо.

```
echo Клюет! Скорее подсекайте [1] 

set /p answer= 1 
ping -n 6 127.1 >NUL

if %answer%==1 (
goto Win
) if else %answer%==0 (
goto Lose 
) else (
goto Lose 
)
```